# Selection.OnAction = "Workbookname!Macroname"

Tags: vba, excel

Say you have two Workbooks one called “MyWorkbook” and the other called “PatchMyWorkbook”. Both workbooks are open at the save time. The “PatchMyWorkbook” has a macro to add a button and assign an existing macro of “MyWorkbook” to “MyWorkbook” The existing macro in “MyWorkbook” is called “PrintPage”

```
Windows(“MyWorkbook”).Activate  
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(665.25, 43.5, 89.25, 45).Select
Selection.OnAction = "PrintPage"
```

This does not cause an error while the “PatchMyWorkbook” code executes but the newly added buttons macro will point to “’PatchMyWorkbook’!PrintPage” rather than just “PrintPage” of the “MyWorkbook”

Question: How can you set the “OnAction” for a macro button across workbooks so that the macro will point to the current workbook not the workbook from where the macro has been created?

Comment: I've tried things like     MyWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("ButtonName").OnAction = "'" & myWbk.Name & "'" & "!" & "PrintPage" but it doesn't work. It still refers to the workbook that runs the macro.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion `.OnAction property` should be set in this way:

```
Selection.OnAction = myWbk.Name & "!PrintPage"
```

By the way, the idea from your comment (changed a bit below):

```
Selection.OnAction = "'" & myWbk.Name & "'" & "!" & "PrintPage"
```

is working for me as well (Excel 2010).

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the name of the sheet or module where `PrintPage` is defined.

```
Dim methodName As String
With <module or sheet where 'PrintPage' is defined>
    methodName = "'" & MyWbk.Name & "'!" & .CodeName & ".PrintPage"
End With
MyWbk.Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("ButtonName").OnAction = methodName
```

The single quotes surrounding `MyWbk.Name` are important.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way is :

```
workbooks("name_of_workbook").Worksheets("name_of_sheet").Shapes("name_of_button").OnAction = "name_of_your_macro"
```

Just substitute the different "name_of_..." by your names.

Does it work?