# Have a sheet button run a xlam (add-in) macro

Tags: excel, vba

Is that not possible?

My main goal is to create a button/shape with VBA on the sheet that will run a xlam sub. But I can't connect a button to the xlam sub.

I try to right click on the button and click on... I don't know. Run macro? I have Swedish Excel so I don't know what the option is called in English.
But the options I get is only the local macro that is in the workbook not the xlam.

I try to record a macro of what happens when I connect a local macro to it, and I get:

```
Selection.OnAction = "Makro3"
```

So the obvious would be to replace that with:

```
Selection.OnAction = "'STAGE.xlam'!urklipp"
```

But the code does not run and I get no errors.
I can however use "pure" VBA inside a local workbook macro:

```
Application.Run "'STAGE.xlam'!urklipp"
```

But that means the local workbook needs to have a macro to run the xlam which is not possible since the local workbook is an export of data from SAP.

Anyone know a way to run a xlam sub from a button/shape?

Comment: Maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685929/selection-onaction-workbooknamemacroname) you'll find something usefull.

Comment: @barneyos Thank you! There was a answer that worked. (or at least gave me the clue what the problem was).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the module was not included in the OnAction.

```
 Selection.OnAction = "'STAGE.xlam'!Modul1.urklipp"
```

Comment: So is it working correct at you? When I'm calling `Me.Shapes(1).OnAction = "'myMacro.xlam'!Module1.RunmyMacro"` from sheet module where my button is, my remote macro is starting and running well.

Answer (score -1):

Sub Button1_Click()
Application.Run ("myfile.xlam!XYZ")
End Sub

(XYZ is what you want to run).
Let me know if this works

Comment: Take a look at the following link to write a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer